# Вторичное окно tkinter отказываеться закрываться

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Я столкнулся с проблемой: при открытии вторичного окна по нажатию кнопки оно должно создавать папку на диске с и закрываться но после создания папки оно не закрываеться, у меня Python 3.8 работаю в Python Idle

вот часть кода:

```
def setup():
    setup = Toplevel() 
    setup.geometry("300x300")
    setup.title("setup")
    setup["bg"] = "white"
    setup.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    setup.iconbitmap('setup.ico')
    b = tk.Button(setup, text='setup', command= lambda: startsetup())
    b.place(x=260, y=274)

def startsetup():
    os.mkdir("c://TEST")
    setup.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменная `setup` в функции `setup` - локальная (кстати, называть разные вещи одинаковыми именами - это отличный способ запутать самого себя, поэтому лучше так не делать). Функция `startsetup` эту переменную не видит, а видит только функцию `setup` под этим именем (при запуске кода из консоли после нажатия на кнопку у вас пишет что у функции `setup` нет метода `destroy`).

Один из вариантов решения - расположить функцию `startsetup` внутри функции `setup`, тогда функция `startsetup` будет видеть локальные переменные внешней функции:

```
def setup():
    setup = Toplevel() 
    setup.geometry("300x300")
    setup.title("setup")
    setup["bg"] = "white"
    setup.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    setup.iconbitmap('setup.ico')

    def startsetup():
        os.mkdir("c:/TEST")  # Прямые слеши не нужно экранировать - только обратные
        setup.destroy()

    b = tk.Button(setup, text='setup', command=startsetup)  # вместо лямбды без параметров можно передавать саму функцию
    b.place(x=260, y=274)
```